# Created event in System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have a folder. When a file copied to that folder I need to rename it. Hence I have used a `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` to do that. And I have implemented a service to do it.

My code as follows.

```
private System.IO.FileSystemWatcher FSWatcherTest;

FSWatcherTest.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FSWatcherTest_Created);

--------

private void FSWatcherTest_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //Some code
    File.Move(oldfilepath, newfilepath);
    //some code
}
```

When I copy a text file from my local machine it is working finely. But when I copy I large file from the network this is not working. Error is when it is copping this will fired. So the file is not accessible to this method. But I’m wondering why this is fired while it’s copping.

I’m using `VS 2008` and `C#` for this application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What runtime error are you receiving?

Comment: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. mscorlib

Comment: Maybe the `filesystemwatcher` triggers once the file is created, not once it's been fully copied (i.e. the copying process is still using the file)..

Comment: yes that is the case. But normally Created means it should fired after its created successfully.

Comment: So im looking this method to go foreword. Im try to open the file in while loop. once i got open it successfully only i called rename function. Is that the best way or is there any better method ?

Comment: How large is the file?  I remember running into problems on our network where the Windows file protocols broke crossing a domain boundary but only on very large files.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution:

If there is no way to know when the file has been fully copied, you could keep trying to do it until it works.

Something like this:

```
private void FSWatcherTest_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    FileMover(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e);
}

private void FileMover(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try{
    //Some code
    File.Move(oldfilepath, newfilepath);
    //some code
    }
    catch
    {
         //Call an asynchronous method that will wait 1 second then call FileMover again       
         //with the same arguments,
         //a BackGroundWorker would be perfect for that job.
    }
}
```

Comment: See also this blog which has a similar idea. http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/jschreuder/archive/2006/07/06/12886.aspx (Note, I thought think you need to use a BackGroundWorker since the event is already running in a different thread.

Comment: I mentionned the BackgroundWorker just to be bulletproof, I don't have a test case ;)

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be I don't think you need to use BackgroundWorker since the event is already running in a different thread

Answer (score 0):

Just found this snippit

```
        Dim F As Short = FreeFile()
        FileOpen(F, sFile, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.LockReadWrite)
        FileClose(F)
```

Would it be possible to wrap it in a 'WHILE' loop so it waits until the copy process is free?